# kineticJS " box.on('dragend', alert("drag end"))" doesn't fire at end of drag

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I need need to trap the  "dragend" event of a shape being dragged to update properties palette for that shape. I have tried the code below, but this function only fires when the shape is created and not at the end drag.

```
 box.on('dragend', alert("drag end"))
```

Comment: is it possible to put a jsfiddle with the example on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kinetic node.on method takes a function declaration as its second parameter.

```
circle1.on("dragend",function(){alert("dragend")});
```